# Is there a data storage where I can access data directly via array index instead of hash key? Redis? MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, redis, database, nosql

I need an external C/C++ memory efficient (!) data storage for a Java app which does not have the downside of a normal database lookup (b tree) but which uses my IDs as array index. Is there an open source solution for this? I implemented this in C++ in-memory only, but I would like to have a "storage to disc" option in case of a crash or for backup. Also Java binding would be cool.

E.g. redis looks good but when reading [the docs](http://redis.io/topics/introduction) I see that in general things are accessed by hash keys which have O(1) only in theory - or can I somehow force that the hashing scheme matches the storage index? And also lists are not appropriated as they are implemented as linked lists. Or what about mongodb?

And yes, I really need that fast read access (write can be "okayish slow" :)) - it is no premature optimization but if there is no alternative I'll try redis before rolling my own. Also Java is not possible (as I said: memory efficient ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a remote key-value store, the overhead is very often dominated by the network and protocol management rather than data access itself. That's why with efficient key-value stores (like Redis for instance), almost all the operations actually have the same cost.

The Redis [benchmark](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) page contains a good illustration of this point.

In other words, in the context of an in-memory remote store, and considering only the latency, a random access array will have the same exact performance than a hash table, and even less efficient O(log n) containers like red-black trees, B-trees, etc ... will be quite close.

If you really want maximum performance, I would suggest to use an embedded (i.e. in-process) store. For instance, both [BerkeleyDB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/programmer_reference/am_conf.html#am_conf_intro) and [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html#tcfdbapi) provide disk based random access containers for fixed-length records.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I have ~ 100 million smallish records. Do you have experience with those tools at this 'scale'?

Comment: And what is the difference to Kyoto Cabinet?

Comment: Provided the items fit in memory, they both can work at this scale. You will probably have to study all the configuration parameters to fine tune the storage layer though. For more safety, I would partition the store (i.e. easier to handle 10 partitions of 10M items, than one partition of 100M items).

Comment: Kyoto (written in C++) is a sibling project of Tokyo Cabinet (written in C). They are distinct products. Unfortunately, the random access container for fixed-length records is not anymore provided with Kyoto. Probably the author decided it was not that useful.

Comment: If you don't want to use an embedded store and are not afraid of a bit of system programming, one last option is to rely on memory mapped files (see the Boost.Interprocess library for a convenient C++ wrapper ).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why do you think I need partitions for more safety? I'm still investigating and the mmap sounds reasonable although a bit time consuming ;)

Comment: Partitioning is good for general scalability. If your data structure is a tree, partitioning will decrease the number of levels. If it is a hash table, it will decrease the number of empty buckets or long chains. If it is a simple array, it will avoid the OS to struggle finding a very large *contiguous* memory block. If you use parallel algorithms, it will provide better locking granularity, etc ...

Comment: thanks a bunch again :) (SO wanted me to move this discussion to chat ... :))

Answer (score 0):

[KDB](http://kx.com/) is the go-to solution for this problem in the financial systems (algo trading) world.  Be prepared to have your brain melted by the syntax though. Oh, and it is not open source.